# How to count multiple columns in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables for saving user queries in my site. One for Tickets and the other for Ticket Replies. What I want is to count total tickets + total replies + total tickets with different status's. I can successfully count total tickets and total replies but I am having problem with counting ticket status's.

The problem:
When I use following query, it shows total new and open tickets but as the query is a JOIN query, it shows total status's of all rows (which means it's showing sum of status's for all replies and not all tickets).

```
SELECT  COUNT(tr.ticketid) totalReplies, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(t.ticketid)) totalTickets,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.status='Open' THEN 1 END) totalOpen,
        SUM(CASE WHEN t.status='Close' THEN 1 END) totalClose
FROM `tbl_ticket` t 
INNER JOIN `tbl_ticket_reply` tr ON tr.ticketid = t.ticketid
```

Hope I am making myself clear. I will explain it with an example. Let's say we have total following records:

```
total tickets: 10
total replies: 20
```

Let's say, half tickets are opened and half closed. Then it should show 5 open, 5 closed. But instead, it gives 10 open and 10 closed.

Update:
I do not want to group my query by status as it would then distribute my total tickets among status's.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this code may work for your data

```
SELECT  
COUNT(t.ticketid) AS totaltickets, 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.status='Open' THEN 1 END) AS totalopen, 
SUM(CASE WHEN t.status='Close' THEN 1 END) AS totalclose
,(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_ticket t 
    LEFT JOIN tbl_ticket_reply tr ON t.ticketid=tr.ticketid
) AS total_replies
FROM tbl_ticket t
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `GROUP BY status` in your query.

You need something like:

```
select count(tickets) tkt_cnt, count(replies) rep_cnt from mytable
group by status
```

On your query, following change should be working.

```
SELECT
    COUNT(tr.ticketid) totalReplies, 
    COUNT(DISTINCT(t.ticketid)) totalTickets,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.status='Open' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalOpen,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.status='Close' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) totalClose
FROM `tbl_ticket` t 
INNER JOIN `tbl_ticket_reply` tr ON tr.ticketid = t.ticketid
GROUP BY t.status
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. But, I don't want to group by status as it would then show 2 rows for total tickets and total replies. I don't want my tickets and replies to be distributed among status.